# Web Audio: No sound in right channel

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create a custom panning control using the Web Audio API, but I can't get any sound to come out of the right channel using the channel splitter and merger nodes:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
    destination = context.destination,
    osc = context.createOscillator(),
    gainL = context.createGainNode(),
    gainR = context.createGainNode(),
    splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2),
    merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);

osc.frequency.value = 500;

osc.connect(splitter);

splitter.connect(gainL, 0);
splitter.connect(gainR, 1);

gainL.connect(merger, 0, 0);
gainR.connect(merger, 0, 1);

osc.noteOn(0);

gainL.gain.value = 0.1;
gainR.gain.value = 0.5;

osc.noteOff(2);

merger.connect(destination);
```

Am I missing something obvious here? There's a JSBin preview of the above code here: http://jsbin.com/ayijoy/1/

I'm running Chrome v24.0.1312.57, just in case that's of any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is this happens because the Oscillator outputs a mono signal. Try using a stereo source and you should probably have more luck.

Edit: here's how you can pan a "mono" signal (bypass the splitter, since there is no stereo signal to split, and connect the oscillator directly to the two gains. Then connect the two mono signals to the merger after adjusting the gain for each channel) http://jsbin.com/ayijoy/16/

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks; it turns out I was missing something obvious after all.

Comment: That said, though, I thought up-mixing from mono -> stereo was automatically done when connecting a mono source to a stereo destination. The spec here isn't so clear: http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#UpMix

Consider connecting an oscillator directly to the destination node: the sound will play in both L and R channels, suggesting an auto up-mix; I would've thought the same would happen in my question's scenario...

Comment: In general, upmixing does happen automatically.  However, the Splitter node is for you to mess with the signal directly, so it does not.  From the spec: '[AudioSplitterNode] has a single input, and a number of "active" outputs which equals the number of channels in the input audio stream. ...  Any outputs which are not "active" will output silence and would typically not be connected to anything.'

Comment: Thanks, Chris - I reread the AudioSplitterNode section of the spec not too long before you posted that comment; sometimes it's a wood vs. trees situation: stare at a problem for long enough and one can easily lose sight of the original issue!

Comment: An oscillator node only has one output, so connecting it to two gain nodes is wrong.

Comment: Not really, @Asher, you can connect a node with a single output with multiple destinations. Or did you mean something else is wrong?